# Scala Searching for a certain Char in a string

Tags: string, scala, char

Problem: I would want to know at which indexes a specific Char is at. For example If I want to know the char T in the string "BETTER". I would want it to produce 001100 as the result from the method or something close to that, so you can tell by just looking at it, where the T are placed.
I know there is CharAt(Int) but I'm not able to produce something long the lines of 001100

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? Have you looked at the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/)? - you can solve this with a single and very simple `map`

Answer (score -1):

```
"BETTER".map(c => if(c == 'T') '1' else '0')
```

You can of course improve it by creating a function that takes the string and char as arguments.